# Android interface implementation for multiple screen sizes and densities

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm developing an application and i need it to fit all screen sizes and densities.
I created 4 folders for the resources (drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi,drawable-hdpi,drawable-xhdpi) and 4 xml layouts. But i'm confused a little about many points:

1- If I have a Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1 (mdpi screen) with a 1280 x 800 screen size and a Samsung Gio (mdpi screen) with a 320 x 480 screen size, how can I make the "layout-mdpi" folder including the xml layout file for medium dpi, fits these 2 devices having the same dpi but 2 different screen sizes (Galaxy tab is much bigger than Samsung Gio)?

2- I'm creating my png's using Photoshop, these png's must be saved with 320dpi,160dpi,240dpi..? Or all the resources must be saved in 72 dpi but different sizes?

3- I tested a star icon on my Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1 (mdpi screen) having 32x32px size, dunno why my icon is blurred!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make all 4 different sizes images and put that images according to folder.And also set the property  in menifest like this.

```
<supports-screens
        android:anyDensity="true"
        android:largeScreens="true"
        android:normalScreens="true"
        android:smallScreens="true" />
```

Comment: I made this property in my manifest and my resources are organised in 4 folders, but my problem is when you have 2 devices having the same density in dpi ( so android will use the layout and the resources in the mdpi folder and mdpi xml file) but 2 different screen sizes, how will the same xml layout and same resources fit these 2 devices? And I also have 2 questions posted above.

Comment: you have to make the two different folder for same mdpi like drawable-mdpi and drawable-mdpi-v5

Comment: You mean in "v5" 5 inch? Can you please help me for these 2 questions:
2- I'm creating my png's using Photoshop, these png's must be saved with 320dpi,160dpi,240dpi..? Or all the resources must be saved in 72 dpi but different sizes?

3- I tested a star icon on my Samsung Galaxy tab 10.1 (mdpi screen) having 32x32px size, dunno why my icon is blurred!

Comment: size is depend on your layout that means which type of image you use and where you want to set.If you fit in of the folder then calculate the other image's size.Like i have created the images for my dialpad like ldpi=45 *32 mdpi= 90 *60 hdpi= 135 *94 xhdpi= 180 *125

Comment: Yes but i mean while i'm creating the images on Photoshop, all images will have 72 dpi as resolution but different size (When i'm saving the png)? Can you help me why the star icon 32x32px on the Samsung galaxy tab 10.1 is blurred?

Comment: bcz samsung galaxt 10.1 device required some more size than you have given.Just assign the diffrent size and check.Also one more thing you have assign the px in size right.So please remove that and give the size in dp.